# Amazon Web Services: Vertical DB scaling magic?

Tags: database-design, amazon-web-services, scalability

My team is considering AWS for hosting our Ruby on Rails app. Most of the work done by the app will be storing tons of data in the DB (for now we're assuming it'll be PostgreSQL, as RDBMS fits our needs well), retrieving it, doing some analytics on it and then displaying the results to the user on the screen.

We're concerned about long term scalability. I don't envision the CPU to be an issue at any point (depending on where we decide to do the processing, doing it in the DB might be a really bad idea), but I believe that the DB itself will be the bottleneck. I understand horizontal scaling: get more DBs, shard the data, done. However I've heard people claim that AWS (or S3 in this case?) is so magical that you might not need horizontal scaling, not for a while at least.

I don't see the magic though. All I can tell is that the best you can do, vertically at least, is renting one of those 60gb RAM instances with high IO priority. Not only you end up paying a ton more (compared to throwing a dozen cheapo sharded DB instances at the problem), but you still have one single bottleneck that gets hammered by your entire system. In my experience having one single DB machine doesn't scale well at all, but you can get away with it at first while you have either no users or you're still prototyping.

Am I understanding this correctly, or is there more than meets the eye?

Answer (score 0):

If you go with Amazon RDS which is basically an instance of EC2 running a DB server, you can't achieve vertical scale. 
Choosing a non-hosted solution means you set up your own solution and responsible for the clustering on different EC2 instances. Amazon cloud just helps you get as much "instances" as you will need to scale, but doesn't help you with the software itself.
Other option is choosing Amazon DynamoDB which does do vertical scale for you